# Replacement of toilet on wooden block

Tags: bathroom, toilet, drain, replacement, flange

I am trying to replace a toilet which is on top of a block of wood. Before I uninstalled the old toilet, I thought that I would be able to remove the block of wood but now that I have removed the old toilet, I am not able to remove the wood block. After further inspection, I noticed that when I try to lift the wood block, the supply line moves which leads me to believe that the wood block is affixed to the plumbing some how. I have tried unscrewing the flange and also the two screws at the front of the block and it still isn't coming free. On top of this, the new toilet doesn't fit on the wood block so I am now forced to find a way to remove it.

What do I need to do to remove this block and install the new toilet?

[image: top view]
[image: left view]
[image: front view]
[image: right view]
[image: side tape measure]
[image: top tape measure]

Comment: Do you have access to the waste pipe on the underside of the floor?

Comment: Flange was set way to high. Is this s concrete slab floor? Or maybe this was a clever way of elevating the toilet fir handicap height

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean This toilet is on the second floor so technically I should be able to access the waste pipe but I don't know how I would go about that

Comment: @Kris Not a concrete floor--this toilet is on the second floor so it's just subfloor and tile

Comment: My guess is that the ceiling below isn’t deep enough to allow a proper installation; making a toilet taller is way easier than making a ceiling lower or floor higher.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean So what do you think I should do about this? The wood block is too small for the new toilet.

Comment: Bigger block? :)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Right, I guess that _is_ the most obvious answer! So I tried getting the flange off of the wooden block and couldn't. Do you think that the flange was glued to the drain after the wooden block was placed there? If so, how would I even go about removing the block?

Comment: The flange is glued in place holding down the block.  You'd have to cut out the flange to remove the block, but unless you have clearance below to redo the flange correctly, you should leave it as is.  And new toilet is going to expect the flange to be level with the floor.